# I am trying to update my database but its not updating and the query is correct in CMD

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `title`, `slug`, `content`, `sorting`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `Pages` AS `Page` WHERE `Page`.`id` = '51';
Executing (default): UPDATE `Pages` SET `title`='gaffer',`slug`='home',`content`='Home testingaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',`updatedAt`='2018-04-25 21:02:07' WHERE `id` = 'home'

**The main issue is that when i am getting my Edit form its giving me the id in the API cause i wrote the code for it but when i am updating its giving me the ID which is mine SLUG thats why my database is not updated any help would be appreciated**

```
            /*
            * GET Editing page
            */
            router.get('/edit-page/:id', function (req, res) {


                models.Page.findOne({
                    where: {
                        id:req.params.id
                    }         
                })
                .then(function(page){
                       id=page.id,
                       title=page.title,
                       slug=page.slug,
                       content=page.content
                })
                .then(function(){
                    res.render('admin/edit_page');
                })
                    .catch(function(err){
                    console.log(err);

            })
        });
        /*
        * POST Edit Page
        */
        router.post('/edit-page/:id', function (req, res) {

        req.checkBody('title', 'Title must have a value.').notEmpty();
        req.checkBody('content', 'Content must have a value.').notEmpty();

        var title = req.body.title;
        var slug = req.body.slug.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
        // if (slug == " ")
        //     slug = title.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
        var content = req.body.content;
        var id = req.body.id;

        var condition={
            where:
            {id:req.params.id}
        };
        var values={
            title:req.body.title,
            slug:req.body.slug,
            content:req.body.content
        };
        options={multi:true};
        var errors = req.validationErrors();

        if (errors) {
            res.render('admin/edit_page', {
                errors: errors,
                title: title,
                slug: slug,
                content: content,
                id:id
            });
        } else {
            // models.Page.find({
            //     where: {
            //         id:req.params.id
            //     }         
            // })
            // .then(function(page){
            //     if(Page){
                models.Page.update(values,{...condition,...options})  //ES6 sprade operator       

                .then(function(page){

                    res.render('admin/pages');

                })
                .catch(function(err){
                    console.log(err);
                })
            }
            });
```

Comment: Could not properly understand what you mean by **which is mine SLUG thats why my database is not updated any help would be appreciated** ? Do you mean your **req.params.id** is **slug**

Comment: in my code i write id=req.params.id and my slug is req.body.slug when i am getting its returning the true url but when calling updating method id should be id=1 but id ='home'

Comment: Can you do console.log on `{...condition,...options}` and see what output you get there ?

Comment: Also check your post url, is that returning slug ?

Comment: thanks bro its have been solved id is getting 'home' from where i changed from req.params.id to req.body.id

Comment: Farhan bhai app kou facebook prr request bhaej dou agr node mae koi masla ayaa tou whn pochne mae assani hu gee